# I need to implement a flutter app, when 2 phones come near it must alert the 2 phones

Tags: android, django, flutter, geolocation, gps

I have less experience in this field. I have no idea to implement this feature. I dont know what to google. Please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the location of the device and store the lat and long of the device in the backend(probably AWS if you are using it!).

Every device registers to your app will be sending its realtime lat and long to your backend.

You can have some sort of computation or graph-based analysis in the backend and check if two devices have a really small difference in their location parameters. If so, then you can use SNS(Available in AWS) and Firebase, to send a push notification, to notify the user.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the algorithm? Just tell me what to google.

Comment: Algorithm as in? Please be clear. You can google how to use SNS or FIrebase to send push notifications.

Comment: As in matching the 2 near locations